# How to reuse array variable to store data in localStorage without saving the old values within array in React.js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to reuse a single variable array to save image URL in local storage depending on what page the user is on.

Ex. If the user is on page 1 and adds images to page 1, I then save the page the user is on and the image src the user clicked on, so if the user adds 3 images to page 1 then there will be 3 images src's in that array and so on, now if they go to page 2 instead of having an empty array it takes up the same values as page 1. How would I make it so if user goes to page 2 it starts out as an empty array but when the user goes back to page 1 it should still keep the same images src they clicked on for page 1.

```
  let imageStorageArr = useMemo(() => [], []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const imageLSDataModel = {
      page: current, // current page user is on
      imageSrc: imageStorageArr, // image src's gets pushed to array with OnClick method 
    };
    localStorage.setItem(
      `imageSrc${current}`,
      JSON.stringify(imageLSDataModel)
    );
  }, [current, imageStorage, imageStorageArr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```js
const [currentImg, setCurrentImg] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem(`imageSrc${current}`)) {
            let value = localStorage.getItem(`imageSrc${current}`);

            if (value) {
                setCurrentImg(JSON.parse(value));
            }
        }
}, []);
```

And you use currentImg in your div to diplay it.